# Flask login can't use custom view

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

In my app i'm using [Flask login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) application. But i can't configure it to use custom view.

My project structure:

```
ProjectName
-app
--auth
----models.py
----views.py
app_settings.py
config.py
extensions.py
```

app_settings.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter
from app.auth.views import auth
from extension import db, login_manager
from config import BaseConfig
from app.auth.models import User, Role, load_user


# For import *
__all__ = ['create_app']

DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS = (
    main,
    auth
)


def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
    if blueprints is None:
        blueprints = DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS

    app = flask.Flask('app', instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object(BaseConfig)
    configure_blueprints(app, blueprints)
    configure_extensions(app)

    configure_hook(app)

    configure_error_handlers(app)

    return app


def configure_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)

    # Flask-Login
    #  https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    login_manager.user_loader(load_user)
    login_manager.login_view = "/auth/login"

    @app.teardown_request
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        from extension import db
        db.session.remove()
```

I tried: `login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"` too. But nothing helped. It continue using standard login view and template.

auth/views.py

```
from flask.ext.login import login_user


auth = flask.Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')


@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Here we use a class of some kind to represent and validate our
    # client-side form data. For example, WTForms is a library that will
    # handle this for us, and we use a custom LoginForm to validate.

    form = LoginForm(flask.request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Login and validate the user.
        # user should be an instance of your `User` class
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        login_user(user)

        flask.flash('Logged in successfully.')

        next = flask.request.args.get('next')
        # next_is_valid should check if the user has valid
        # permission to access the `next` url
        return flask.redirect(flask.request.args.get('next', '/'))

    return flask.render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)
```

Comment: try it without the leading `/`   try just `login_manager.login_view = "auth/login"`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't help :(

Comment: please post `auth.views`   you need to pass the endpoint to login_view,

Comment: done, check it please. I took it from documentation

Answer (score 0):

try `login_manager.login_view = "login"`  You are going to want to point it to the URL of the login view. In this case that is defined by `@auth.route('/login')`

Only the endpoint `login` should be required.

Comment: problem that it ignore my login manager object, and use standard app login manager

Comment: This Article Might help you, I have a feeling your blueprint route is not properly registered, but I have not done much work with Blueprints. https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-web-applications-with-flask-part-ii/          ... scroll to integrating flask-login